# knockout div scrolling in foreach

Tags: html, knockout.js, magento2

I'm new in knockout. I want to do like if foreach contains more than 5 array then in div vertical scrolling should be apply , otherwise scrolling should be remove.

how to do this using knockout ?

HTML :

```
<div class="temp-autocomplete-suggestions">
    <!-- ko foreach: autocompleteData -->
     <div class="temp-pro-autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="text: $index">
        <div class="temp-pro-suggest-pro-img">
            <img class="temp-pro-img-responsive" data-bind="attr: {src:imageUrl}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="temp-pro-suggest-pro-data">
            <div class="product-line product-name">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href:productUrl}" target="_blank"><span data-bind="text:productName1"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-line product-price">Price: <span data-bind="value:productPrice"></span></div>
            <div class="product-des">
                <p class="short-des" data-bind="attr : {id:productName1}">ProductName1: <span data-bind="text:productName1"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="temp-pro-additem">
            <button id="temp-pro-search-item-list" class="temp-pro-materialize-btn">Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**Note : autocompleteData is ko.observableArray([])**

Comment: hi.. how was the previous error resolved?

Comment: There are bracket syntex issue in span tag. Thanks for help. +1 for help to solve that.

Comment: Can you please solve this question?

Comment: Writing answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `style` binding in the div just outside the `foreach` binding, and check the length of `autocompleteData`.

```
<div class="temp-autocomplete-suggestions" 
     data-bind="style: { overflowY: autocompleteData().length > 5 ? 'scroll' : 'auto', 
                         height: autocompleteData().length > 5 ? '300px': 'initial' }">
    <!-- ko foreach: autocompleteData -->
     <div class="temp-pro-autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="text: $index">
        <div class="temp-pro-suggest-pro-img">
            <img class="temp-pro-img-responsive" data-bind="attr: {src:imageUrl}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="temp-pro-suggest-pro-data">
            <div class="product-line product-name">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href:productUrl}" target="_blank"><span data-bind="text:productName1"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-line product-price">Price: <span data-bind="value:productPrice"></span></div>
            <div class="product-des">
                <p class="short-des" data-bind="attr : {id:productName1}">ProductName1: <span data-bind="text:productName1"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="temp-pro-additem">
            <button id="temp-pro-search-item-list" class="temp-pro-materialize-btn">Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Example (see in full page view):

```js
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autocompleteData = ko.observableArray();
    self.addData = function(){
        self.autocompleteData.push({});
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.hello {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="temp-autocomplete-suggestions" 
     data-bind="style: { overflowY: autocompleteData().length > 5 ? 'scroll' : 'auto', height: autocompleteData().length > 5 ? '300px': 'initial' }">
<!-- ko foreach: autocompleteData -->
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>

<button data-bind="click: addData">Add to Array</button>
```

Comment: Scrollbar display succesfully. But, I just want to vertical scrollbar. Current, it's display horizontally scrollbar.

Comment: Do you know about how to get all parent value when click on Click Here Button ?

Comment: yes.. use $parent.(whatever item you want from parent)

Comment: I want to get that value in js file.  <button id="temp-pro-search-item-list" class="temp-pro-materialize-btn" data-bind="click:myCustom">Click Here</button>
        </div> So, In myCustom function I want to get.

Comment: ok.. can you give me an example of what item you want to get?

Comment: I got it :) Than Q so much. @Ray

Comment: Hey can you please help me to solve my new question ?